# get first row in a group and assign values

Tags: pandas, aggregate-functions

I have a pandas dataframe in the below format

```
 id   name  value_1  value_2
 1    def   1        0
 2    abc   0        1
```

I would need to sort the above dataframe based on id, name, value_1 & value_2. Following that, for every group of [id,name,value_1,value_2], get the first row and set df['result'] = 1. For the other rows in that group, set df['result'] = 0.

I do the sorting and get the first row using the below code:

```
df = df.sort_values(["id","name","value_1","value_2"], ascending=True)
first_row_per_group = df.groupby(["id","name","value_1","value_2"]).agg('first')
```

After getting the first row, I set first_row_per_group ['result'] = 1. But I am not sure how to set the other rows (non-first) rows to 0.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`df.groupby(...).cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to get a counter of rows within the group which you can then manipulate.

```py
In [51]: df
Out[51]:
     a  b  c
0  def  1  0
1  abc  0  1
2  def  1  0
3  abc  0  1

In [52]: df2 = df.sort_values(['a','b','c'])

In [53]: df2['result'] = df2.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c']).cumcount()

In [54]: df2['result'] = np.where(df2['result'] == 0, 1, 0)

In [55]: df2
Out[55]:
     a  b  c  result
1  abc  0  1       1
3  abc  0  1       0
0  def  1  0       1
2  def  1  0       0
```

Answer (score 2):

`duplicated` would be faster than `groupby`:

```
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'name', 'value_1', 'value_2'])
df['result'] = (~df['id'].duplicated()).astype(int)
```